# Controlling VMs using Python scripts

Tags: python, linux, scripting, virtual-machine

I want to manage virtual machines (any flavor) using Python scripts. Example, create VM, start, stop and be able to access my guest OS's resources.

My host machine runs Windows. I have VirtualBox installed. Guest OS: Kali Linux. 
I just came across a software called libvirt. Do any of you think this would help me ? 
Any insights on how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should look into docker ...

Comment: So, you want to run Kali and you have no pointer an how to access and control a VM from the outside? That is a weired combination.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Is that a VM ?

Comment: @KlausD. Host: Windows. Guest: Kali. I need a method that uses python scripts to manage virtual machines.

Comment: docker is like a VM ... (in windows it runs with a vm) ... but slightly different ... you should really look into it ... It sounds like exactly what you are looking for

Comment: follow the directions here to install docker https://docs.docker.com/windows/ (it includes Oracle VirtualBox (if you dont already have it) ... it also explains setting up an image and interacting with it over through the command line ... I think you would just do something like `docker run kali`

Answer (score 0):

For aws use boto.

For GCE use Google API Python Client Library

For OpenStack use the python-openstackclient and import its methods directly.

For VMWare, google it.

For Opsware, abandon all hope as their API is undocumented and has like 12 years of accumulated abandoned methods to dig through and an equally insane datamodel back ending it.

For direct libvirt control there are python bindings for libvirt.  They work very well and closely mimic the c libraries.

I could go on.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'm kind of not familiar with the terms you are using. Are aws, GCE, OpenStack and Opsware virtual machines ? Can you be more verbose with your explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

follow the directions here to install docker https://docs.docker.com/windows/ (it includes Oracle VirtualBox (if you dont already have it)

```
#grab the immage
docker pull kalilinux/kali-linux-docker

#run a specific command
docker run kalilinux/kali-linux-docker <some_command>

#open interactive terminal to "docker image"
docker run -t -i kalilinux/kali-linux-docker /bin/bash

if you want to mount a local volume you can use the `-v dst src` switch in your run command

#mount local ./training/webapp directory into kali image @ /webapp
docker run kalilinux/kali-linux-docker -v /webapp training/webapp <some_command>
```

note that these are run from the regular windows prompt to use python you would need to wrap them in subprocess calls ...